# Instruments not showing energy log in Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13.1.3

Tags: xcode, testing, logging, instruments, energy

Instruments not showing energy log in Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13.1. I saw that the chart for energy log used to show 0/20 (example) for measuring energy, but for me it just doesn't show any data. I tried it with and without a cable and with recording energy log in instruments as well as straight from device itself.

If that's not possible, is there another way to compare the energy log of two different app versions that isn't the Organizer option in Xcode.

[image: Xcode instruments screenshot]